# DSL in the Browser (Ruby Like DSL for Javascript)

Tags: javascript, ruby, typescript, webassembly, transpiler

I really love Ruby when it comes to writing DSL's. (Domain specific language)

The DSL syntax is cleaner and more readable than DSL's written in other languages that I have tried.

I would like to move a lot of my DSL's to a browser based environment, and that means I need a DSL that runs in Javascript.

I do not believe that native Typescript or Javascript is as readable as a Ruby when it comes to DSL's, but I could be wrong on that.

I was wondering if there was some type of language that was good for DSL's that transpiled to Javascript, or maybe even an AST for producing higher level languages that would be a superset of Javascript.

I have written many of them and generally they follow the Builder (with Director) design pattern.

This example builds DrawIO diagrams using Domain Specific Language instructions.

```rb
DrawioDsl::Drawio
  .diagram(theme: :style_11)
  .page('Style-Plain', margin_left: 0, margin_top: 0, rounded: 0, background: '#FFEADB') do
    grid_layout(wrap_at: 8)

    interface(theme: :style_07) do
      format
        .header('IPerson')
        .field(:field1, type: :string)
        .field(:field2, type: :string)
        .method(:full_name, type: :string)
    end

    klass do
      format
        .header('Person')
        .field(:field1, type: :string)
        .field(:field2, type: :string)
        .field(:age, type: :integer)
        .field(:birthday, type: :date)
        .method(:full_name, type: :string)
    end

    klass(h: 280) do
      format
        .header('Custom HTML')
        .p('David')
        .b('Cruwys')
        .hr
        .h1('h1')
        .h2('h2')
        .h3('h3')
        .h4('h4')
        .h5('h5')
        .h6('h6')
        .ul_s
        .li('li')
        .li('li')
        .ul_e
    end
  end
end
```

[image]

Comment: Behold, [Ruby in the browser](https://github.com/ruby/ruby.wasm).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will investigate it

Comment: Wow, that is a cool project

Answer (score 0):

[Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) is an excellent language for implementing DSLs and can be transpiled into javascript.  Here is an early example of a [DSL in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-safe-builders.html)